# NodeJS prototype parameter not defined

Tags: node.js, object, prototype

I try to use the Database model that I create in the other prototype functions but it returns always the Error that the Model is not initialized, so this.model is empty.
Is there something wrong with my Object in general, because all solutions I found to this topic had no problems with the 'this' inside the prototype functions.

My Node version: 11.9.0

```
function CRUD (collection /* String */, schema /* mongoose.Schema */) { 
    this.model = db.model(collection, schema)
    console.log('Model initialized ')
}
CRUD.prototype.create = function (req, res, next) {
   if(!this.model) throw new Error('No Model initialized')
   this.model.create(req.body, (err, data) => {
        if (err){
            res.send('Can`t create Object')
        } else{
            console.log(data, ' created')
            next()
        }

    })
}
CRUD.prototype.read = function (req, res, next) {
    if(!this.model) throw new Error('No Model initialized')
    if(req.query){ // for GET requests
        var filter = req.query
    }else if(req.body){ // for other requests
        var filter = req.body
    }else{
        var filter = {} // no filter
    }
    this.model.find(filter, req.body, (err, data) => {
        if (err){
            res.send('Can`t find Object')
        } else{
            req.body = data
            next()
        }  
    })
}
```

The Code worked already when I use instead of 'this.model' 'CRUD.prototype.model', but I had to change it because the model was kind of a static parameter in the prototype and i need a different models for every CRUD object.

Comment: How are you calling the functions and instantiating the `CRUD` instance?

Comment: with `const cConfig = new CRUD('Config', new db.Schema(schemas.Config))` and the functions are used as a middleware in my endpoints

Answer (score 0):

`this` is defined by how you call the function. If you are passing these functions as callbacks to something like an express route, you lose the `this` binding. You would need to pass the functions with something like:

```
cConfig = new crud('Config', new db.Schema(schemas.Config))
app.get('/', cConfig.create.bind(cConfig))
```

Here's a simple example that might help show the problem:

```js
function someObj(f_name){
  this.f_name = f_name
}

someObj.prototype.talk = function(){
  console.log(this.f_name)
}

let me = new someObj("mark")
me.talk() // works as expected

/* some function that takes a callback */
function runCB(cb){
  cb()
}

// pass in talk:

runCB(me.talk)          // doesn't work because this binding is lost 
                        // the CB is just passed as a function reference
                        // and so we no longer know it belongs with `me`

runCB(me.talk.bind(me)) // but it works it you hard bind it back
runCB(() => me.talk())  // also works because we call it as me.talk()
```

Comment: Your solution with `cConfig.create.bind(cConfig)` did not work for me, but your answer helped me alot to understand my problem better. Now I come up with a kind of ugly solution to add the context to my request like `app.get('/', (req, res, next) =>{ req.DBContext = cConfig; next()}, db.read, (req, res)=>{})`. That solves my problem for now but I will revisit it to come up with something better.

Comment: Okay, glad it helped @OliKuroh -- it was kind of guess because your question didn't include any information about how you're calling the functions, which is important in this case.